# Reading error with getErrorStream fails with an exception

Tags: java, message

i need to read some error message in java, i tried to do this in getErrorStream and then readLine, but i got exeption.

Comment: Until I see evidence to the contrary, I'll assume that the question is coming from a script kiddie hacker wannabe; but it's nevertheless a valid programming question (it could have an answer, given the right circumstances) so I don't agree with the folk(s) who want to close it.

Comment: i don't want to do anything illegal,it's a challenge i need to solve in some site.

Answer (score 2):

TrueCrypt isn't your Java program, and Java doesn't have a reasonably workable way to reach into another program's dialog to read the message.

`getErrorStream()` would work if TrueCrypt output a text to its standard error, but since it has a dialog to show the user it has little reason to do so.

It's possible that TrueCrypt returns a non-0 exit status if it fails, and you could catch that by using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("TrueCrypt.exe")`, waiting for the resulting process to finish (using `Process.waitFor()`) and then checking the exit status you get there. However, you still need someone (or something) to hit the <kbd>Ok</kbd> button for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can't

That error message is being displayed on the window manager of the operating system which is not readable.

Your attempt to read from the standard error are failing, probably because that application doesn't write to the standard error in first place.

Comment: I disagree with the second part of your answer: Reading from stderr, if done correctly, will not hit an error just because there is nothing being written there. Instead, I suspect that even if he's doing `exec()`, he has an error in his program, as it isn't trivial to set up all the streams plumbing on an exec'd process.

Comment: Of course, if done correctly. Done incorrectly may fail if there is nothing to read and he's forcing the read somehow. As for the currect state of the question we can't tell.

Answer (score 0):

The source code for Truecrypt is available, so you could modify it to output to stdout/stderr.